# Independently config test an .htaccess file

Tags: apache-2.2, testing, continuous-integration

I know `apachectl` has the `configtest` option, but as far as I can tell it's only for checking the entire config chain for the system apache. I would like to have a tool that can test an individual .htaccess file for errors as part of a continuous integration toolchain. Is there any way to do that with or without apachectl?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/125081/how-can-i-perform-a-syntax-check-on-an-htaccess-file-in-a-shared-hosting-enviro is related.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407865/validating-htaccess-before-deployment is related.

Answer (score 1):

I came across few online tools to validate `.htaccess` Syntax/Directives and few basic things [htaccess-validator](http://shop.alterlinks.com/htaccess-validator/htaccess-validator.php) and [code syntax checker and validator](http://www.lyxx.com/freestuff/002.html).

PS: To narrow down analyses/error and speed up validation, limit the no. of Directives while validation.

Comment: Are you suggesting I write wget or curl scripts to use these web services? Under CI testing I may end up hitting them too heavily and get banned…

Comment: No! I'm suggesting you to upload/paste .htaccess content in respective online tools! Btw, why'd you heat them too heavily? do you need mass validation?

Comment: …but the point of the question was continuous integration.

Comment: Ah, i'm not aware of such commandline tool, which could validate it like we do by `apachectl` & `configtest`. Seems, we need Open Source Community support. :D

Comment: @kojiro issue solved?

Comment: Sadly, no, I've never found a tool that can validate an individual htaccess file under CI use cases.